# How do I find diff between two files on my local machine using git?

Tags: git, git-diff

I have two files new.txt and new2.txt. I want to find the differences between these two files and was thinking to use git diff for the same but I couldn't. This is what I have done till now and respective errors -

1. git init in the local directory.
2. git diff new.txt new2.txt => produced no response
3. Added both files to the git and then repeated same above command. => no response.
4. git diff --cached new.txt new2.txt => found diff between new.txt and new.txt only before and after git add.
5. git diff full_path_to_file/new.txt full_path_to_file/new2.txt => no response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git diff` is meant to do much more than compare two specific files, but it does have a mode in which it will do so:

```
git diff --no-index new.txt new2.txt
```

will do the job.  You do not need to be in a Git repository.  All of these arguments (`--no-index` and the two specific file names) are (sometimes) required (sometimes you can omit the `--no-index`).

Answer (score 1):

using git diff to compare 2 files is a strange way to compare 2 files. git diff is usually used to compare a file from the local branch with the same file on the remote branch (on the git servers).
You can simply use the diff binary such as:

```
diff newt.txt new2.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan.. :)